# Can Active X controls be installed and run in Windows Sandbox on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, activex, windows-sandbox

ActiveX controls are terrible, and should be vanquished from the Earth, but sometimes the need arises to use such terrible things and when one does, is it possible to run it from Windows [Sandbox](https://www.pcmag.com/feature/369427/how-to-safely-run-software-with-windows-10-sandbox/5) ?

Comment: What OS are you running in Sandbox. If Windows 10, I don't think it supports Active-X any more, but if you run Windows 7, it might support Active-X

Comment: Have you tried? Sandbox seems designed to allow things to be installed for testing. So did you try installing or running the ActiveX there?

Comment: @john OP linked to the Sandbox they are working with, which is an optimized VM built in to recent versions of Windows 10.